# Attach Database to Java Application

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, exe

I am working on a standalone java application. I have used MSSQL as backend database. I created exe file for that project using eclipse--->export
But when i install it on another machine i also need to install sql on that system.
So can i attach database to that application so that after creating exe and when i install it on another machine there is no need to install the sql application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will that database only hold data for that one install / user? In that case an embedded database (Derby is shipped with the JDK) should be the way to go here.

Comment: Yes it will be one install/user. Suppose if we use MS SQL so when in developing phase we have to install sql on our system but when we have to deliver the system to client then how to manage the database on his machine?. I will read more about derby to manage the database. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score -1):

Use embedded database, such as H2

Comment: Can we use H2 with standalone applications?